# How to filter or drop spans before sent it to collector in micrometer with Otel in spring 3?

Tags: open-telemetry, spring-3, distributed-tracing, micrometer-tracing

**Is there any way to drop unwanted spans in micrometer-tracing with opentelemetry before sent it to collector?**

I tried to filtered spans by configuring custom Sampler from openTelemetry api.

if management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0 , then it works expected.

but if management.tracing.sampling.probability=0.0 then, it drop parent span and sends child spans.

**Expectation**: It should not sent any spans, if probability=0.0

```java
    @Override
    public SamplingResult shouldSample(Context context, String traceId, String name, SpanKind spanKind, Attributes attributes, List<LinkData> list) {

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")) {
          return SamplingResult.drop();
        } else {
             // put condition for record and recordAndSample based on sampling probability.
            return SamplingResult.recordAndSample();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return CustomSampler.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

@AutoConfigureBefore(OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ OtelTracer.class, SdkTracerProvider.class, OpenTelemetry.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TracingProperties.class)
public class SamplerConfig {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Sampler customSampler() {

        Float samplerProbability = this.tracingProperties.getSampling().getProbability();
        return Sampler.parentBasedBuilder(Sampler.traceIdRatioBased(samplerProbability))
                .setRemoteParentNotSampled(new CustomSampler())
                .setLocalParentNotSampled(new CustomSampler())
                .setLocalParentSampled(new CustomSampler())
                .setRemoteParentSampled(new CustomSampler())
                .build();
    }
}


Please suggest if there is any other good way to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SpanExportingPredicate](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/blob/v1.2.1/micrometer-tracing/src/main/java/io/micrometer/tracing/exporter/SpanExportingPredicate.java) from Micrometer Tracing or set up the [Sampler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.2.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.java#L99-L104) in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Grzejszczak. it was really helpful. I am using SpanExportingPredicate to filter the spans.

Comment: Great, can we mark this as answered?

Comment: Yes, @Marcin Grzejszczak we can. Again, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, I guess you need to mark it as answered then :)